# Remote Access to MySQL database of a website using VB.NET 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, remote-access

Im trying to connect a vb.net2010 project to a database of a website. I have already added % as host in the remote mysql access of cpanel, and turned off my firewall.

Here is the code I used:

```
    Dim MySQLconn As New MySqlConnection
    MySQLconn = New MySqlConnection("server=www.mysite.net; User Id=myusername; pwd=mypassword; database=mydatabase; port=3306;")
            Try
                MySQLconn.Open()
                MsgBox("Sucess", vbOKOnly)
                MySQLconn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

An error is caught which says "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

I hope I can get help or suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please verify that the MySQL server listens on external interfaces.

In most *nix Environments it defaults to localhost, that means you can't connect from a remote  machine, even if you disable a firewall.

This is either achived via `skip-networking` or more common via `bind-address localhost` in the my.cnf file.

Try setting

```
bind-address x.x.x.x
```

where x.x.x.x is the IP adress of www.mysite.net and restart your mysql server.

**Update**

As you are using cpanel, have you whitelistet your ip adress as mentioned here? 
http://kb.liquidweb.com/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/
http://www.yourhowto.net/how-to-make-a-remote-mysql-connection/

Basically there are three things to do:

1. Whitelist your IP or % as a wild card (you already have done this)
2. Add Firewall rules (not sure if that is required for cpanel, you could verify that with a port scanner
3. Your user needs permission to access the database (`GRANT ... ON ... TO user@%`) from a remote host. If you run this command from a command prompt you should get a password prompt `>mysql -h www.mysite.net -u user -p`, try to log in. If you get an access denied for user@% you need to grant permissions for user@your-ip-address-or-hostname.

Comment: Id just like to clarify if where can I edit the bind-address? I only have access to the Cpanel of the website.

I already added '%' as access host under 'Manage Remote MySQL Access' of Cpanel

Comment: I added another link http://www.yourhowto.net/how-to-make-a-remote-mysql-connection/ which should help.

Comment: Sir can I ask what particular tool can I use to be able to edit this bind-address? or where exactly can I edit this?
I have read that this is in a "my.cnf" file and can be accessed via SSH.
This is the only alternative I haven't tried.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: The file is usually located in the `/etc` or `/etc/mysql` directory. Excute this command to figure out where `find / -name my.cnf
` However, tools like plesk or cpanel normally store the system configuration somewhere else and overwrite config files evertime you change something in the webgui. That means your change propably won't last forever, but to track down the issue is worth a try. It also could be that cPanel uses a config file on a different location. On a side note: If your server has multiple ip-adresses, you can bind to any address with bind-address `0.0.0.0`

Comment: How can I get into /etc or /etc/mysql directory?
Is this located in the server itself? All I have access is to cPanel.

Comment: If you don't have root access, you can't. Are in a shared hosting environment or do you own the server?. If yes, your request would affect other customers as well, which might not like the additional security risk that comes with making a mysql server publicly available.

Comment: I don't own the server. I guess this means this is impossible for now? I think I have to think of some alternatives for now.
Thank you for the replies sir.

Comment: You could ask your provider to find a solution for you. For example you could use iptables to forward remote request on 3306 from a specific ip to localhost with masquerade (that way, the mysql server sees a request from localhost), however I am not an iptables expert, and serverfault would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you @SchlaWiener for the help,  
I found a free hosting, db4free.net and had no problems connecting. I guess I have to settle with this for now.